# Erro de sintaxe ao usar UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Erro:

```
/* Erro SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM pedido a,
                        tipofornecimento b
                    ' at line 7 */
/* Affected rows: 0  Registros encontrados: 0  Avisos: 0  Duração de 0 of 1 query: 0,000 sec. */
```

**Consulta:**

```php
$sql = "(SELECT 
        a.id,
        a.cliente_id, 
        a.arquiteto_id, 
        a.vendedor_id, 
        b.nome as tipofornecimento,
    FROM {$this->t_pedido} a,
        {$this->t_tipofornecimento} b
    WHERE
            a.fornecimento_id = b.id
        {$where})

        UNION ALL

    (SELECT 
        c.id,
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
        c.valor as valor
    FROM {$this->t_devolucaoparcelas} c,
        {$this->t_movimentos} d 
    WHERE 
        c.devolucao_id = d.id)
    ";
```

Comment: Só uma ressalva o problema da UNION é no banco de dados SQL, e não PHP

Answer (score 1):

**You have an error in your SQL syntax  near 'FROM pedido a, tipofornecimento b ' at line 7**

```
(SELECT   
   a.id,
   a.cliente_id, 
   a.arquiteto_id, 
   a.vendedor_id, 
   b.nome as tipofornecimento, <------- virgula a mais
FROM {$this->t_pedido} a,
```

Antes do from existe uma virgula que não deveria estar ali, a mensagem de erro da uma pista sobre isso.

Answer (score 0):

No union, se eu considerar que não existem erros nas suas variáveis, os campos devem ter o mesmo nome, o mesmo tipo e a mesma ordem nos dois SQL para que não haja erros.

```
(SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.cliente_id, 
    a.arquiteto_id, 
    a.vendedor_id, 
    b.nome as tipofornecimento <----
FROM Pedido a,
    Tipo b
WHERE
    a.fornecimento_id = b.id)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
    c.id,
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    c.valor as valor <----
FROM Devolução c,
    Movimentos d 
WHERE 
    c.devolucao_id = d.id)
```

Eu acredito que a coluna `b.nome` não tem o mesmo tipo que a `c.valor`.
Também tinha uma vírgula depois do `b.nome tipofornecimento`